# What is the linq equivalent for the TSQL with join and group by?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to create a linq query from the following sql.

Couldn't find an example that had a join in it with multiple tables and a group by that had different fields from different tables.

```
select t2.field1, t1.field1, count(t2.field1) from Table1 t1
join Table2 t2 on t1.pkfield = t2.pkfield
group by t2.field1, t1.field1
having count(*) > 1
order by t2.pkfield1
```

Tried the following:

```
var test = 
  from t1 in db.Table1
  join t2 in db.Table2 on t1.pkfield equals t2.pkfield
  group x by (t1.field1, t2.field1)
  select t1.field1, t2.field2
```

Comment: You couldn't find any examples so you expect us to do it from you? At least attempt something and show us that, even if it doesn't compile/work

Comment: I'm believe that nobody can translate this to linq because your sql is broken. What is `s`, what is `p`?  Why do you grouping by `t1,field1`? Should it be `t1.field1`? Please fix your typos and add c# classes that represent Table1 and Table2

Comment: @AleksAndreev, thanks (fixed)

Answer (score 1):

You do not post entity classes and input examples so I can't verify my code. But I hope that concept is clear

```
db.Table1.SelectMany(t1 => db.Table2.Select(t2 => new { t2.field1, t1.field1, t2.pkfield1 }))
  .GroupBy(x => new { t1Field1 = t2.field1, t2Field1 = t1.field1 })
  .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
  .OrderBy(g => g.Min(x => x.pkfield1))
  .Select(g => new { g.Key.t1Field1, g.Key.t2Field1, g.Count() });
```

In code above `db` is your custom `DbContext` and `SelectMany` will be translated into `inner join`

Comment: If I wanted to return this from a method, what would the return type be? Or do I need to make a local class with these 3 properties in it?

Comment: @Rod you can create a new class and select into it, or use c#7 value tuples

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it in a single query, but I have accomplished something similar as follows. Hope it helps you or at least points you in the right direction.

```
var result = from p in person
             join o in orders on p.OrderId equals o.OrderId
             // build your custom object with columns from multiple tables.
             select new { o.OrderId, p.OrderId}; 

// now group the result
var grouped = result.GroupBy(x => x.OrderId)
                    .Where(y=> y.Count() > 1);
```